# Binding a custom dependency property to a property in View Model not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a Dock Panel inside the Main Window. In the Dock Panel, there is an object (say object1) of a class inherited from **UserControl** class (Instantiation is happening in XAML itself). object1 has a collection of objects (say object2) of another class which is inherited from **Framework** element. In object2, there is a **dependency property** which I need to bind to a Property in **View Model** of the **Main Window**. How can this be achieved?

When I tried to bind, the SetValue and GetValue of Dependency property are not getting triggered, i.e., binding is not happening.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DockPanel x:Uid="DockPanel_3" Name="DockPanel_3" Grid.Column="1"
          Background="{DynamicResource LayoutManagerBackground}">
<local:LayoutManager x:Uid="m_LayoutManager" x:Name="m_LayoutManager"
          Margin="5"  Visibility="Collapsed">
<local:LayoutManager.Layouts x:Uid="m_Layouts">
<local:Layout x:Uid="local:Layout_1" LayoutName="{x:Static
          VisionUIConstants:LayoutNames.MeasurementSetup}"
          IsSelected="True" LayoutDescription="{StaticResource 
          TTDMeasurementView}" IconBrush="{Binding StitchIcon}">
```

**Layout Class**

```
public DrawingBrush IconBrush
    {
        get { return (DrawingBrush)GetValue(IconBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IconBrush.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconBrush", typeof(DrawingBrush), typeof(Layout), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
        {
            PropertyChangedCallback = OnIconChanged,
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
        });

    private static void OnIconChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue != e.NewValue)
        {
            // code to be executed on value update
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction Clemens.
Yes. OnIconChanged is getting called.

Comment: When OnIconChanged is called, the Binding obviously works. Do you still have a problem, or is it solved now?

Comment: The issue is still there

Comment: Ok, what is it then? Your question is "binding ... not working", but apparently the binding *is* working. What exactly is it that does not work?

Comment: When the Dependency Property is bind with Static resource, OnIconChanged is getting called. But when the Dependency Property is bind with Property OnIconChanged is not getting called.

Comment: So you mean `IconBrush="{Binding StitchIcon}"` isn't working? Did you make sure that the current DataContext holds a view model instance, i.e. an object with a StitchIcon property? The DataContext should be set at some parent element of the Layout control, e.g. the the Window, and the Layout control must not explicitly set it in its XAML or constructor.

Comment: So you mean IconBrush="{Binding StitchIcon}" isn't working? YES. Did you make sure that the current DataContext holds a view model instance, i.e. an object with a StitchIcon property? YES. The DataContext should be set at some parent element of the Layout control, e.g. the the Window, and the Layout control must not explicitly set it in its XAML or constructor.- It is not set anywhere else